# Can I modify the HTML generated by sure-fire reports maven plugin?

Tags: java, maven, maven-surefire-plugin

Is there a way to modify the surefire-reports maven plug to include some additional HTML or javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what can be seen in the [source code of this plugin](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/maven/surefire/tags/surefire-2.9/maven-surefire-report-plugin/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugins/surefire/report/SurefireReportGenerator.java?revision=1135752&view=markup) the generation of the report seems to be pretty much hard coded using a content generation framework. It seems to be doubtful that it is possible to sneak in additional code without changing the plugin source itself.